# PHP new DirectoryIterator()

Tags: php

Welcome. I am trying  to display the on-screen images from a folder. Everything works but in the beginning I display two empty pictures. Here is my code:

```
$fileObject = new DirectoryIterator('./images/');

foreach($fileObject as $file)
{
  echo "<img src='".'./images/'.$file."' />";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just skip `.` and `..`:

```
$fileObject = new DirectoryIterator('./images/');

foreach($fileObject as $file)
{
  if ($file->isDot()) continue;
  echo "<img src='".'./images/'.$file->getFilename()."' />";
}
```

Also you probably want `$file->getFilename()` to get the filename.

Comment: `if (!$file->isDot()) continue;` should be `if ($file->isDot()) continue;`

Comment: http://snag.gy/Ed2PJ.jpg     still no department